# How can I obtain the formulas' displays in matlab?

Tags: matlab, formula

I have some complicated formulas, such as;

```
 u = argmin_u (\frac{\alpha}{2} \int_\Omega \chi^2 |\nabla u|^2 ~ dx 
+ \beta \int_\Omega \left(\epsilon |\nabla \chi|^2 
+ \frac{(1-\chi)^2}{4\epsilon} \right)~ dx
```

Is there a way to see them directly? May I save them as an image?
I use text command but it didn't work properly.
Thanks

Comment: Interpretation of tex syntax for 'easy' equations generally works, but I'm afraid your equation here is too sophisticated for MATLAB's tex interpreter.
If you can explain in a broader context what the end result is you're going for, there may be other options.

Comment: Think the problem was in missing `$$` around the formula - see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [display LaTeX expressions on a graph](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/text-with-mathematical-expressions-using-latex.html) using `text` command, setting `'Interpreter'` to `'latex'`. Do not forget to wrap your formula with `$$`:

```
str = '$$u = argmin_u (\frac{\alpha}{2} \int_\Omega \chi^2 |\nabla u|^2 ~ dx + \beta \int_\Omega \left(\epsilon |\nabla \chi|^2 + \frac{(1-\chi)^2}{4\epsilon} \right)~ dx$$';
text(0.1,0.1,str,'Interpreter','latex');
```

You can then save it as an image if you want to, just like you would save any other Matlab figure. Even though it is all possible, a more straight-forward solution would be to just render your formula in a pdf using one of the many LaTeX packages, not Matlab.

[image]